# send email alert through excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to send an email alert from Excel, if the date mentioned in Column F is older than 2 years from the current date.
I am getting error Runtime 462 in the following command
.send
Please suggest.

```
Sub send_files()

        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim FileCell As Range
        Dim bottomA As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim mydate1 As Date
        Dim mydate2 As Long
        Dim datetoday1 As Date
        Dim datetoday2 As Long
        Dim outlookapp As Object



        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        bottomA = sh.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 2 To bottomA

        mydate1 = Cells(x, 6).Value

        mydate2 = mydate1

    Cells(x, 13).Value = mydate2

    datetoday1 = Date

    datetoday2 = datetoday1

    Cells(x, 14).Value = datetoday2

    If datetoday2 - mydate2 >= 730 Then

    Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set OutMail = outlookapp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .to = Cells(2, 17).Value

        .Subject = "Folder Expiration Alert"

        .Body = "Hi"

        .send

        End With



        End If

        Next

     Set outlookapp = Nothing

    Set OutMail = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Run macro when you manual change a cell

To run a macro automatic when you manual change a specific cell you can use the Change event in a worksheet module.The example on this page use Cell A1 and will run the macro if the cell value >200.

1) Right click on a sheet tab and choose view code
2) Paste the event below in the sheet module.
3) Alt-q to go back to Excel

Note: Change YourMacroName to the name of your macro in the code.
If you want the code to work for another cell or more cells you can change the range in the event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 200 Then
            Call YourMacroName
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Example mail macro

Test this example macro to create/display a Outlook mail with a small text message.
You must copy this macro in a standard module and not in the worksheet module, see this page how.

Note: I use .Display in the code to display the mail, you can change that to .Send

Do not forget to change Call YourMacroName to Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook in the Change event.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Cell A1 is changed" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail9.htm

Comment: .Display command is working but with .Send its giving me error Run Time Error 287

Comment: When I am using both .Display command works fine but .Send gives the same error. When I am running this code on my personal computer its working fine but on my office laptop its giving me this error. Is there some outlook settings which I need to change?